# ElasticSearch Script Fields accessable in sort

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to access a script_field inside a sort?

I have

```
search_body["script_fields"] = {
    "test": {
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "inline": skill_rating_algorithm.replace("\n", ""),
            "params" : {
                "param1": {....}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And as sort:

```
search_body["sort"] = {
    "_script": {
        "type": "string",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "inline": "def c = params._fields['test']; return c;",
        }
    },
    "number_of_years_of_experience": {"order": "desc"},
    "value.raw": {"order": "asc"},
}
```

But this only return errors.
I could do a sorting script but i need the value returned in the document as a separate key.

My questions is:
Can i access the script_field "test" inside the sort? (More script_fields will come and i will need different ordering)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to access a runtime field (not a script field) inside sorting. Let's sort dates by month name in descending order

Documents with dates

```
PUT /runtime_field_sort/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{ "date": "2015-01-01" }
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{ "date": "2015-08-01" }
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{ "date": "2015-12-01" }
```

Query with `runtime_mappings` and sort by month name in descending order

```
GET /runtime_field_sort/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "month": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    ZonedDateTime date = doc[params.date_field].value;
                    Month month = date.getMonth();
                    emit(month.toString().toLowerCase());
                """,
                "params": {
                    "date_field": "date"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "month", "date"
    ],
    "_source": false,
    "sort": [
        {
            "month": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "runtime_field_sort",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : null,
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "month" : [
                        "january"
                    ]
                },
                "sort" : [
                    "january"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "runtime_field_sort",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : null,
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "month" : [
                        "december"
                    ]
                },
                "sort" : [
                    "december"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "runtime_field_sort",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : null,
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "month" : [
                        "august"
                    ]
                },
                "sort" : [
                    "august"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```